# Simple VU meter with Lm3915

Tags: led, audio, operational-amplifier

I'm making a VU meter with an LM3915 and I would like to be able to plug my computers audio output into the LM3915 directly and get it to register. I've been  searching the internet for a design but can seem to get any to work without a preamp. Anyone know of a schematic that would work without a pre amp?

Data Sheets

LM3915: http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM3915.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Russell mentioned probably more ways to solve the problem than you care about, but that's Russell: always gives extensive answers :-)

The **Greinacher multiplier** he mentioned at the end of his answer may work, but the diodes may mean that you already need a rather high input voltage, I don't know if it will work well on the line output. (The Greinacher is typically used to multiply power supply voltages, not signals. It can be used to get kilovolts from a 110V or 230V line voltage, for instance.)

Russell also mentioned this opamp amplifier:

[image: non-inverting amplifier]

This is one of the basic opamp circuits, and is easy to understand if you know some basic things about opamps:

- The ideal opamp has infinite amplification
- The output signal is the amplified difference between the inputs
- The ideal opamp has zero input current

The first two items imply that you'll get a finite output signal if both inputs are almost at the same level. And that's what an opamp in a negative feedback system will do: it will try to make the level on the `-` input (called the inverting input) the same as on the `+` input (the non-inverting input). So that will be \$V_{IN}\$, and the current through R1 is

> \$I_{R1} = \dfrac{V_{IN}}{R1}\$

Since there doesn't flow current in the `-` input the current through R1 is the same as the current through R2, so the voltage over R2 is

> \$V_{R2} = I_{R1} \times R2\$

and therefore

> \$V_{OUT} = V_{IN} + \dfrac{V_{IN}}{R1} \times R2\$

or

> \$V_{OUT} = (1 + \dfrac{R2}{R1}) \times V_{IN}\$

So, if we choose R1 = 1k\$\Omega\$ and for R2 a 100k\$\Omega\$ potentiometer, we can vary the amplification between 1x and 101x. This will be a good amplification for a line out signal, and you can set the amplification to the LM3915's full scale.

Comment: My method 2 - using a transformer, probably best suits his overall aims. I think he may want an electronics-less solution so that he can use an existing LM3815 based product. The transformer would allow it to be "just hooked up". Using the cheap transformer that I noted at Jameco as an auto transformer gives a 4:1 stepup with minimal effort.

Comment: @Russell - Yes, but with a transformer the amplification is fixed, and he might want to adjust it to the LM3915's full scale. That's why I mentioned the potentiometer.

Comment: All that. But, the specific challenge was "without a preamp". I agree that an amplifier makes best sense to the electronically inclined. Maybe not so much so to others. // Some of mine are amplifiers. The transformer isn't per se. He could add a pot to a transformer and still have an essentially non-electronic solution. My 4:1 autotransformer is a cheap and known available option. There are of course many other transformers around.

Comment: i have a bunch of lm358 op amps already, would they work?

Comment: @Mike - Yes, an LM358 will do. With a \$\pm\$5V supply you'll have a limited output voltage swing (like \$\pm\$3V) but for the LM3915 this is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The LM3815 needs a minimum of ~1.3V peak signal to fully drive all LEDs.

**Methods:**

- 1 Using PC "speaker" output rather than PC "line" output should provide enough signal to work directly

If not

- 2 $3 non electronic solution.

  A small low cost **audio transformer** will produce a higher voltage if the available voltage is too low to fully drive the LM3915. ([eg **this $2.95 Jameco transformer** can give 4:1 voltage gain](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_125357_-1?CID=PDF)).

  Transformers with higher stepup ratios will be available at similar prices.

  A potentiometer can be added to a transformer if variable sensitivity is required.
- 3 If necessary an "amplifier" using only diodes and capacitors can be made - see text below.

  This is possible because if audio signal level is too low then what is required is a higher voltage DC signal - which can be achieved with a "diode pump".
- 4 If amplified external speakers are used their output could be used to drive the LM3815.
- 5 very cheap and simple amplifier can be made with a single transistor or a single opamp stage. This can be operated from the LM3815 supply.

---

You should be able to operate an LM3915 VU display directly from a **PC speaker connection**. You need a ~ 1.3 V audio peak level to drive the IC to maximum output. 
This corresponds to about 100 mW into an 8 ohm speaker and proportionally less at higher speaker impedances.

You may not be able to operate it from a **PC's "Line" audio output**. Line output levels are typically about 0.5V peak which is "a bit low".  [Wikipedia - line levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level). Some line outputs are at higher levels eg [RCA Sonos system line output](https://sonos.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/sonos.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=338).

If your PC only has a line output port and not a speaker output you may be able to connect to the speaker connections of an external speaker system (which will contain its own amplifier). **An "amplifier" using only diodes and capacitors can be made - see bwlow.**

An LM3915 and other family members have a fixed measuring range of about 1.28 Volt. This is divided into 10 steps. In the LM3915 the steps are logarithmic with 3 dB between steps. Other family members have linear or other responses.

You cannot drive an LM3915 to less than about 1.28V DC and get full output. However, a DC amplifier which amplifies signals by the required amount - probably 2 to 10 times, is extremely simple and easy to build. This could be done with a single transistor amplifier, but using a cheap single supply opamp running from the same supply as the LM3915 would be preferable.

This circuit shows an extremely simple non inverting DC amplifier using half an LM358 [(datasheet)](http://www.national.com/ds/LM/LM158.pdf) or 1/4 of the electrically identical LM324.  Gain = 1 + R2/R1. At the gain needed (< 10) the opamp's offset voltages are not a concern.

[image]

You can buy small audio transformers or salvage them from an older transistor radio. Or a 600 CT: 600 CT transformer can be used as a 4:1 stepup auto transformer. (Join "top" of one winding to bottom of next to make a single winding effectively. Connect Vin to half of one windiong. Take 4x Vout across whole winding.)(Swap polarity on one winding if phase wrong so no output).  ([eg this $2.95 Jameco transformer can give 4:1 voltage gain](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_125357_-1?CID=PDF)).

The truly desparate could make a passive DC voltage multiplier using only diodes and capacitors to "amplify" the audio signal up by using a "diode pump" voltage multiplier.  eg see [Wikipedia on voltage multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier). Diodes should be Shottky type due to low forward voltage (eg [BAT85 and similar - DO34 through hole version](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BAT85.pdf). (I won't mention germanium diode except to say that they are now so rare as to not be worth considering, regardless of technical aspects.) Discuss if interested in more detail.