# Preamp for Magic Eye VU meter

Tags: amplifier, audio, schematics, preamp, tube

I want to build a Magic Eye Tube VU. This tutorial http://www.antimath.info/electro/vu-meter-em84/ says:

> If this circuit is used with a tube amplifier, the “IN” connection in the picture is connected to the anode of the last tube in the amplifier. For an input from another signal source, a preamp stage with a BC171 transistor ( a MOSFET would be a better choice for high input impedance ), is needed.

The tube needs -22v to fully close, but 12v will be enough for me.
I want to use my computer output with the VU meter. There are some diagrams and schematics on the internet, but i don't think they will work with design. Could you recommend a preamp circuit that will work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple VU meter with Lm3915](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18054/simple-vu-meter-with-lm3915)

Comment: An EM84 is not exactly a duplicate of a LM3915..

Comment: Assuming this is for audio use (I can't imagine what else you mean by "computer output" right now), then you (and others here) might examine this reference design before considering a recommended pre-amplifier for it: http://blog.aha.nl/2012/06/all-tube-stereo-level-indicator.html

Comment: No, but the answer covers the OP's question and the question is similar

Comment: From the datasheet, it looks as though cutoff is at about -20 V on the grid, relative to the cathode: http://www.jogis-roehrenbude.de/Roehren-Geschichtliches/Mag_Augen/Baender/EM84_TE.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research i found this amplifier schematic http://afrotechmods.com/tutorials/2017/01/17/how-to-make-a-simple-1-watt-audio-amplifier-lm386-based/
After connecting to input terminal of the vu meter, the eye moves and works great. It doesn't have to close fully for me, so 12v power supply is enough.
:)